# Swift: About assign nil to a var

Tags: swift, option-type

I was trying to learn about swift basics and I encountered this problem:

Assume we have a dic:

```
var presidentialPetsDict = ["Barack Obama":"Bo", "Bill Clinton": "Socks", "George Bush": "Miss Beazley", "Ronald Reagan": "Lucky"]
```

And to Remove the entry for "George Bush" and replace it with an entry for "George W. Bush":

What I did:

```
var oldvalue = presidentialPetsDict.removeValueForKey("George Bush")
if let value = oldvalue
{
    presidentialPetsDict["George W. Bush"] = value
}else
{
    print("no matching found")
}
```

Because I believe removeValueForKey method will return an optional value in case key "George Bush" will not return a value but nil so we need to safely unwrap it by using if let.
However, the solution code looks like this:

```
var oldValue = presidentialPetsDict.removeValueForKey("Georgee Bush")
presidentialPetsDict["George W. Bush"] = oldValue
```

The part I don't understand is that if we want to assign nil to a var we usually do this:

```
var value:String?
value = nil
```

But the solution code above works even though the method returns nil, could somebody explain why it worked because I think in solution we didn't declare oldValue as optional at all.

Comment: Please my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Very good question!

Since your array is defined as `[String:String]` you wonder why the compiler let you assign an optional `String` (so `String?`) to a value.

How can the compiler risk you to put a `nil` inside something that should be a **non optional String** ?

How can this code compile?

```
var oldValue: String? = presidentialPetsDict.removeValueForKey("Georgee Bush")
presidentialPetsDict["George W. Bush"] = oldValue
```

### Here's the answer

Subscript has the following logic, even if the value of the `Dictionary` is `String`, you can use subscript to assign `nil`.
In that case the key is removed from the array.

Look here

```
var numbers: [String:Int] = ["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]
numbers["two"] = nil // it looks like I'm putting nil into a Int right?
numbers // ["one": 1, "three": 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I understand that if you assign nil to a key, that pair in the dictionary will be removed. However, my question is that why var oldValue  = presidentialPetsDict.removeValueForKey("Georgee Bush")  still works? I mean the key is actually "George Bush" so this will return nil to oldValue, but we didn't declare oldValue as option at all.

Comment: Yes you did declare `oldValue` as optional. When you write `var oldValue = presidentialPetsDict.removeValueForKey("Georgee Bush")` the compiler  looks at the type returned by `removeValueForKey` and use it to define the type of `oldValue`. And that type is `String?`. Just `alt+click` in Xcode on the method invocation to see the returned type.

Answer (score 1):

```
var oldValue = presidentialPetsDict.removeValueForKey("George Bush")
```

oldValue gets Optional String because of type inference of the return type.

See the function definition of removeValueForKey
public mutating func removeValueForKey(key: Key) -> Value?